# I'm using JTabbedPane for my quiz program, not sure how to get my buttons to display the answers

Tags: java, swing

As it says, I'm not sure how to loop through the array so it would display the question in each pane, I got 8 panes and each of them should contain a question, I've managed to get it working for one (question 1 displays first entry in the array) but not the others.

Any suggestions?

```
int total = 0;
int counter = 0;
JPanel question1 = new JPanel();
JPanel question2 = new JPanel();
JPanel question3 = new JPanel();
JPanel question4 = new JPanel();
JPanel question5 = new JPanel();
JPanel question6 = new JPanel();
JPanel question7 = new JPanel();
JPanel question8 = new JPanel();
JTabbedPane quiz = new JTabbedPane();
JLabel lblQuestion1 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion2 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion3 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion4 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion5 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion6 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion7 = new JLabel();
JLabel lblQuestion8 = new JLabel();
JButton question1A = new JButton("Answer A");
JButton question1B = new JButton("Answer B");
JButton question1C = new JButton("Answer C");
JButton question2A = new JButton("Answer A");
JButton question2B = new JButton("Answer B");
JButton question2C = new JButton("Answer C");
JButton question3A = new JButton("Answer A");
JButton question3B = new JButton("Answer B");
JButton question3C = new JButton("Answer C");
Problem[] probList = new Problem[5];

public QuizEasy(){

    createLabel();
    createTabs();
    questionsEasy();
    problems();
    nextQuestion();
    updateScreen();
    setTitle("Easy Questions");
    setSize(680,300);

    getContentPane().add(quiz);

    JButton finish = new JButton("Finish Quiz");
    question8.add(finish);


    ButtonHandler phandler = new ButtonHandler();
    finish.addActionListener(phandler);
    setVisible(true);



}

public void nextQuestion(){
    //go forward one question if possible
    counter++;
    if (counter >= probList.length){
        counter = probList.length - 1;
    } // end if
    updateScreen();
}

public void updateScreen(){
    Problem p = probList[counter];
    lblQuestion1.setText(p.getQuestion());
    question1A.setText(p.getAnsA());
    question1B.setText(p.getAnsB());
    question1C.setText(p.getAnsC());
    lblQuestion2.setText(p.getQuestion());
    question2A.setText(p.getAnsA());
    question2B.setText(p.getAnsB());
    question2C.setText(p.getAnsC());

}

public void questionsEasy(){


    question1.add(question1A);
    question1.add(question1B);
    question1.add(question1C);
    question2.add(question2A);
    question2.add(question2B);
    question2.add(question2C);
    question3.add(question3A);
    question3.add(question3B);
    question3.add(question3C);


}

public void problems(){
    probList[0] = new Problem(
              "What is the meaning of life?",
              "Only god knows",
              "42",
              "huh?",
              "B"
            );
    probList[1] = new Problem(
              "What level woodcutting do you need to cut oaks in runescape",
              "15",
              "20",
              "99",
              "C"
            );
    probList[2] = new Problem(
              "Who has recieved the highest amount of oscars?",
              "Walt Disney",
              "You",
              "Leonardo Di Caprio",
              "A"
            );
    probList[3] = new Problem(
              "What is the most spoken native tounge in the world?",
              "English",
              "Ailien",
              "Mandarin",
              "C"
            );
    probList[4] = new Problem(
              "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
              "42 beats per second",
              "10 miles per hour",
              "African or European?",
              "C"
            );

}

public void createLabel(){
    /*JLabel easyQuestion1 = new JLabel();
    easyQuestion1.setText("What level do you need in the game Runescape to cut oak?");
    question1.add(easyQuestion1);*/

    lblQuestion1 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion2 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion3 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion4 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion5 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion6 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion7 = new JLabel("Question");
    lblQuestion8 = new JLabel("Question");

    question1.add(lblQuestion1);
    question2.add(lblQuestion2);
    question3.add(lblQuestion3);
    question4.add(lblQuestion4);
    question5.add(lblQuestion5);
    question6.add(lblQuestion6);
    question7.add(lblQuestion7);
    question8.add(lblQuestion8);




}

public void createTabs(){
    quiz.addTab("Question 1", question1);
    quiz.addTab("Question 2", question2);
    quiz.addTab("Question 3", question3);
    quiz.addTab("Question 4", question4);
    quiz.addTab("Question 5", question5);
    quiz.addTab("Question 6", question6);
    quiz.addTab("Question 7", question7);
    quiz.addTab("Question 8", question8);
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        showSummary();
    }
}

public void showSummary(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have completed the quiz, here are your results"
            );
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    QuizEasy tab = new QuizEasy();

}
```

}

Comment: First and foremost, get rid of all that unnecessary code redundancy by using methods, classes, collections and arrays. Otherwise you (and us) will be stuck with a debugging nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things easier you could create a method called CreateTabs which would build every tab based on your list of problems(probList). See code below:

```
public void CreateTabs() {
    JPanel question = null;
    JLabel lbQuestion = null;
    JButton ansA = null;
    JButton ansB = null;
    JButton ansC = null;
    for (int i=0;i<probList.length;i++) {
        question = new JPanel();
        lbQuestion = new JLabel(probList[i].getQuestion());
        question.add(lbQuestion);
        ansA = new JButton(probList[i].getAnsA());
        ansB = new JButton(probList[i].getAnsB());
        ansC = new JButton(probList[i].getAnsC());
        question.add(ansA);
        question.add(ansB);
        question.add(ansC);
        quiz.addTab("Question " + (i+1), question); 
    }
}
```

In the QuizEasy constructor you would have something like:

```
public QuizEasy() {
    problems();
    CreateTabs();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, I'll give it all a try tomorrow and get back to you guys, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this was after all exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't sure how to loop through the array.